# Конвертация даты в удобно-читаемую форму Python

Tags: python, дата, datetime

Имеется строка

```
2020-01-25T19:27:49.3223932
```

Как ее конвертировать в удобно - читаемую форму? Например 25.01.2020

Пробовал так

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(first_comment, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [15]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [16]: DT.strptime(dt_str.partition("T")[0], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
Out[16]: '25.01.2020'
```